# How to remove previous subview and add new subview to UITableviewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have created cell that can be expanded and collapsed, when the cell is expanded I add 2 subviews and remove those 2 subviews when cell is collapsed. Look at the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
        selectedIndex = -1;

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[cell viewWithTag:TAG_KHMER] removeFromSuperview];
        [[cell viewWithTag:TAG_KOREAN] removeFromSuperview];

        //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [self.tblView beginUpdates];
        [self.tblView endUpdates];

        return;
    }

    if(selectedIndex >= 0){
        NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousPath];
        [[cell viewWithTag:TAG_KHMER] removeFromSuperview];
        [[cell viewWithTag:TAG_KOREAN] removeFromSuperview];
        //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    VocabularyController *vc = [self.vocabularyInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *khmerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    khmerLabel.text = vc.khmer;
    khmerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Hanuman" size:17];
    [khmerLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    khmerLabel.tag = TAG_KHMER;
    khmerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 45, 300, 300);

    UILabel *koreanPro = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    koreanPro.text = vc.korean;
    [koreanPro setNumberOfLines: 0];
    koreanPro.tag = TAG_KOREAN;
    koreanPro.frame = CGRectMake(20, 315, 300, 300);

    [cell addSubview:khmerLabel];
    [cell addSubview:koreanPro];

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.tblView beginUpdates];
    [self.tblView endUpdates];

}
```

What happened is the cell seem not remove the previous one. it displays new text on the old text but when I click on the same cell twice again and then the cell can render the text good.

Can anyone help me how to display it properly.

[image]

After click twice times on the cell.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try and add subviews like that - it's going to lead to confusion, because as you've found out `UITableView` recycles the cells.

Instead, create your own custom `UITableViewCell` subclass that can be switched between the various states you require, and has all the subviews already set up. You can do this in a number of ways - if you're using storyboards you can use prototype cells, or you can use a NIB, or you can create your custom subclass entirely in code (whichever you are most comfortable with).

Basically, don't add subviews to your cells in your table view delegate/datasource calls. Create a custom subclass, and you'll find everything much, much easier.

Comment: My work almost done. 
I have created custom UITableViewCell and put 3 label into cell as you can see in the picture.

But one thing that I am trying to fix is:
The 2nd label contain long string (ex: it has about 3 lines) and I'm trying to change the frame of it but it's height no changed. and the 3rd label still stay the same where it was.
Actually, 2nd label height must be bigger and the 3rd label must be after that.

Can you tell me how to solve this problem?
Thank you so much.